# Chef-server-ctl reconfigure/ Creating Admin User on chef server

Tags: linux, chef-infra, centos7, rhel7

I am fairly new to Linux (and brand new to chef) and I have ran into an issue when setting up my chef server. I am trying to create an admin user with the command

> sudo chef-server-ctl user-create admin Admin Ladmin admin@example.com
> examplepass -f admin.pem

but after I keep getting this error:

> ERROR: Connection refused connecting...
>
> ERROR: Connection refused connecting to https://127.0.0.1/users/, retry 5/5
> ERROR: Network Error: Connection refused - Connection refused
> connecting to https://..., giving up
> Check your knife configuration and network settings

I also noticed that when I ran chef-server-ctl I got this output:

> [2016-12-21T13:24:59-05:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers Running
> handlers complete
> [2016-12-21T13:24:59-05:00] ERROR: Exception
> handlers complete Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 01 seconds
> [2016-12-21T13:24:59-05:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to
> /var/opt/opscode/local-mode-cache/chef-stacktrace.out
> [2016-12-21T13:24:59-05:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the
> stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
> [2016-12-21T13:24:59-05:00] FATAL:
> Chef::Exceptions::CannotDetermineNodeName: Unable to determine node
> name: configure node_name or configure the system's hostname and fqdn

I read that this error is due to a prerequisite mistake but I'm uncertain as to what it means or how to fix it. So any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server does not have a valid FQDN (aka full host name). You'll have to fix this before installing Chef server.

Comment: Will I have to completely uninstall chef after I do this, or can I set the full hostname then restart the machine and then run chef-server-ctl reconfigure?

Comment: It depends on how sad rabbitmq is. Try the simpler route first? You could also manually reinit the rabbit database but that is probably more annoying than it is worth.

Comment: I followed this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html) to change the full hostname but I still got the same error.

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with how to configure a Linux host name I would find someone at your company to mentor you or hire someone to assist.

Comment: I configured everything properly. It actually turned out to be an issue with memory. The machine didn't have enough RAM. Thank you for the input.